# How does setting in.flight.requests.per.session=1 and retries > 1 helps in preserving order of message in Kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In one of the books I am reading it says, if ordering is critical we recommend setting in.flight.requests.per.session=1 when retries > 1

How does this help in message ordering specially when message is being sent asynchronously?

Say 5 msgs A, B and C, D,E is meant to go to partition 1.

A is sent successfully, B is sent (will fail in future) , C is sent and now since B failed is sent again.
Keeping in.flight.requests.per.session=1 just makes sure that while B is being retried, D and E will not make it to the partition ahead of B but it still doen't help in stopping C to go ahead of B.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken , max.in.flight.requests.per.session does not exist in Kafka but max.in.flight.requests.per.connection do.

Anyway , the producer will use one batch per partition and the max.in.flight request.connection should be set to 1 indeed to ensure strict ordering guarantee on retry scenario :

***The documentation says :***

> Allowing retries without setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection
> to 1 will potentially change the ordering of records because if two
> batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is
> retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch
> may appear first. Note additionally that produce requests will be
> failed before the number of retries has been exhausted if the timeout
> configured by delivery.timeout.ms expires first before successful
> acknowledgement. Users should generally prefer to leave this config
> unset and instead use delivery.timeout.ms to control retry behavior.

Comment: Can't I do this by just using a synchronous send from producer?

Comment: You can but its a tradeOff between high throughput and delivery guarantee i would say